# How to run the doctest for a single function in python3?

Tags: python, doctest

How do I run the doctest for only a single function in python using the command line? I can  `python3 -m doctest  -v main.py` but this will run all the doctests in main.py. How do I specify one function to call the doctest on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the code in main.py that runs the doctests. You can change that code to [test a specific function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080157/is-it-possible-to-only-test-specific-functions-with-doctest-in-a-module) by calling `doctest.run_docstring_examples()`.

When that code runs `doctest.testmod()` however, you cannot limit testing to a single function from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, seems like there isn't a way to do it from the command line!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using my [doctestfn](https://pypi.org/project/doctestfn/) package:

```bash
pip install doctestfn
```

It can then be used to run tests for a single function in a module as follows:

```
doctestfn myfile.py myfunction
```